# Java - Is it safe to do deepCopy of UUID field as this.uuid = original.getUUID()?

Tags: java, uuid, deep-copy

For the following class, when I do deep copy, is it safe to write code as

```
this.id = original.getId();
```

In my test, it seems OK, as when I want to update the UUID field, I always assign it with a new UUID instance(I couldn't find any function which can modify an existing UUID instance). In this case, this copied one will never have side effect to original instance.

```
public class Container {

    private Type type;
    private UUID id;
    private Container c;

    // public constructors here

    protected Container(Container original, boolean deepCopy) {
        this.type = original.getType();
        this.id = original.getId();
        // for deep copy of id field, should I write as:
        // this.id = new UUID(original.getId().getMostSignificantBits(), original.getId().getLeastSignificantBits());
        if (original.getC() != null) {
            this.c = deepCopy ? original.getC().deepCopy() : original.getC();
        }
    }

    // getter and setter here

    public Container deepCopy() {
        return new Container(this, true);
    }

}
```

However in the project I maintained now(Not created by me), I find the deep copy code is as this:

```
this.id = new UUID(original.getId().getMostSignificantBits(), original.getId().getLeastSignificantBits());
```

No doubt, this is a correct solution.

My question is: is it safe to do this as

```
this.id = original.getId();
```

Maybe this is a stupid question, thanks for your time to help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's safe. UUID is immutable.

As you observed, you never modify the instance, you just assign a new instance to your member. So, you never effect any other code's UUID, even if they originally had a reference to the same one that you have.

The 'copy' code is totally unneccessary.

Answer (score 2):

A "deep copy" means that every object in your object tree is a *new* instance. By executing

```
this.id = original.getId();
```

you are using the *same* UUID object as the original object.

The code you found is how you make a *copy* of the UUID object such that it has the same value. It is unnecessary to copy a UUID for safety, as the UUID class is [*immutable*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object); from its [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html):

> A class that represents an **immutable** universally unique identifier (UUID).

However there may be other considerations that support making a copy.

Comment: ♦, yeah, you are right. I am "cheating" without following the rule of deep copy. And in some cases, this may bring troubles. Thank you so much.